# Проблема с циклом while: если есть логин, то его нельзя использовать в регистрации

Tags: ajax, php, циклы, javascript

В общем вот сценарий обработки, здесь просто, сперва проверяется стрлен полей, потом проверяется на повтор пароля, вот дальше беда, выборка из базы, делаю цикл, потом проверку, если логин не равен логину из бд то ригестрируй если не равен выводи сообщение что такой логин занят, выводит, но в цикле, логин занят логин занят и т.д. Вроде правильно написано, но если в цикле то будет записей столько выводиться, сколько записей в бд, как выйти из этого тупика.

```
$userstable = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");

if(strlen($name) > 1 AND strlen($email) > 1 AND strlen($music) > 1 AND strlen($password > 1 AND strlen($repassword) > 1){

    if($password == $repassword){

        while($relogin = mysql_fetch_array($userstable)){
            if($name != $relogin['name']){

                $insertusersdb = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (`name`, `email`, `genre`, `password`) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$music', '$password')");

                echo '<script>$("#submitregister").html("Идет регистрация...");</script>';

                if($insertusersdb == true){
                    echo '  <script>setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#register-block").css("margin-top","-295px");
                    $("#errormass").fadeOut(250).empty();
                    $("#submitregister").html("Заригестрироваться").fadeIn(2000);
                    $("#formregistrationmain")[0].reset();
                    },2000);
                    $("#submitregister").html("Регистрация завершена"); 
                    </script>'; 
                    echo '<p style="color:green;">Спасибо за регистрацию</p>';                          
                }   
            }
            else{   
                echo 'Извените, но такой логин уже занят!';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

по теме, а почему не ограничиться одним запросом в базу на совпадение логина?

```
SELECT 'name' FROM users WHERE 'name'="{$user_entered_name}"
```

и если есть результат, то тогда не давать регистрировать. зачем всю базу перебирать?
Кстати, по вашей логике первое же несовпадение инициирует запись в базу :)

Comment: да знаю, обрабатывается аяксом, главное работает, но вот с проверкой ника проблема, попробовал твоё, точно, верно) затестил, ответа вообще не поступает

Comment: точноли не поступает? возможно ответ должен быть в виде json'a?
код javascript'a не помешал бы.  
+ возможно гдето еще ошибка есть, включите отображение ошибок и посмотрите ответ от сервера чемнить типа firebug.